# I have an array of objects, but I only want to display the first two until they are deleted and the next in line appears

Tags: angular, postgresql, express

```
for (let index = 0; index < this.currentCompetitors.length; index++) {
   if(index < 2) {
console.log(this.currentCompetitors[index]);
     this.currentCompetitors = response;
 }
}
```

I think ultimately this does not work, but i figured ill post what I have.
I need for it to loop through the entire array, but only display two.

I want my function to loop through the array of lets say 5 objects, but only display the first two, until the first objected is deleted and the second and third object takes its slot.
Maybe I can do this with ngClass?

If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function to display the first two items:

```
const firstTwo = (arr: any[]) => arr.filter((item, index) => index < 2);
```

Usage:

```
const myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
display(firstTwo(myArray));  //where display is your method for displaying
```

If you are trying to display the content in an Angular component, you can do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of firstTwo(myArray)">
  {{item}}
  <button (click)="delete(item)">&times</button>
</div>
```

where `delete()` method is defined in the control and removes the item from the array.

```
delete(item) {
  //assumes item has a key property id
  const index = this.myArray.findIndex(el => el.id === item.id);
  if (index >= 0) { 
    this.myArray.splice(index, 0); //remove the item
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want always the first two elements you can do that simple

```
let foo = [this.currentCompetitors[0], this.currentCompetitors[1]];
```